# Updated from Focal Fossa to Ubuntu 20.04 Jammin Jellyfish - Reboot Fail

Tags: boot, 22.04

I received the Jammin Jellyfish update this morning. I followed procedure and all was going well until I re-booted. Black screen. I held button to turn off. I restarted and it would start reboot and then back to black screen. I can get to safe mode but no idea what I am looking for or to do. Very new to Linux. I am using a Lenovo T14 . Thank you in advance.

Comment: 20,04 is not Jammy Jellyfish but Bionic, so it's not clear to which version you upgraded.

Comment: Reboot into GRUB (look it up if you don't know how). Select an older kernel to boot from.

Comment: Thank you! I can reboot into GRUB but I am clueless what to look for or what to do to select an older kernel.

Comment: I was able to reboot using recovery mode.